# How to make a Spline in C++

Tags: c++, math, plot, spline

Given a list of **n** points[x, y] of a plot/graph how to calculate a path(set of points) for a spline passing through them.

Function prototype:

```
Spline CalculateSpline(std::list<int> x, std::list<int> y) {
    //here goes the code
}
```

Here is a sample plot with a few points:

[image]

Comment: Mmm it already is continuous. Do you want your plot look like infinitely differentiable function? Maybe you want to draw a [spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)#Algorithm_for_computing_natural_cubic_splines)?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-splinechart-example.html

Answer (score 0):

There's actually an entire website for examples of this: https://www.qcustomplot.com/

This example may be useful: https://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/demos/simpledemo